# Updating correctly keys in dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary (d2) and I have to create a new dictionary (new_dict)  containing only keys that satisfy a condition.

This is my code:

```
d2 = dict((y,x) for x,y in d.iteritems())

new_dict={}
for name in list:
   for keyx in d2:
       if name in keyx:       
           new_dict=dict((keyx,d2[keyx]) for v in d2.itervalues())
           print new_dict
```

But when I print new_dict I obtain a new_dict for each key :

```
{key:value}
{key2:value2}
ecc..
```

How can obtain an unique dictionary??

Comment: Have you tried mutating the existing dictionary instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it with an example.

```
>>> f={'c':1,'d':2,'e':3}
>>> l=['c','d']
>>> {i:f[i] for i in f if any([k in i for k in l])}
{'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

For your use case it will simply be.

```
new_dict = {i:d2[i] for i in d2 if any([k in i for k in list])}
```

That said, please **refrain from using variable names like `list`**.

Also, instead of

```
d2 = dict((y,x) for x,y in d.iteritems())
```

you could just do

```
d2 = {y:x for x,y in d.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (You're right, I used list only as example here ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Just update your code like -

```
d2 = dict((y,x) for x,y in d.iteritems())

new_dict={}
for name in list:
   for keyx in d2:
       if name in keyx:       
           new_dict[keyx] = d2[keyx]
           print new_dict
```

What you were doing wrong is making a dictionary again and again in the loop...

When you write this -

```
new_dict[keyx] = dict('key' = 'something')
```

A new dictionary is created, and that is the reason of your problem... 
You can solve it in more pythonic ways as in other answers...

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `new_dict` with the new items you find instead of recreating a new dictionary each time. Here's an example:

```
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'ab': 3}
l = ['a']
new_dict = dict([(k, v) for k, v in d2.items() if any(x in k for x in l)])
print new_dict
```

this will output:

```
{'a': 1, 'ab': 3}
```